# How to call a Json object from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to call a JSON object from JavaScript. The JSON object is inside a file called "database2.json". In JavaScript I have a function that is called function check(). I need this function to run the JSON object where I have dates of differents flights (City, company, departure, arrive, etc....). So I've built this:

```
    window.onload = json();


    function json(){
       $.getJSON("/JavaScript/dataBase2.json",function(data){
          $.window.vuelosmadrid = data;
           //console.log(data.vuelosmadrid)
           check()

      }
   }


    function check(){
      var ciudadorigen = window.localStorage.getItem("Origin");
      var ciudaddestino = window.localStorage.getItem("Destination");
      var fechaorigen = window.localStorage.getItem("dateOr");
      // console.log(vuelosmadrid[1].ciudades[0].fechas[1].fecha)
      if (ciudadorigen === "Madrid"){
        console.log("1")
        for (x in vuelosmadrid) {
            console.log("2")
            for (y in vuelosmadrid[x].ciudades) {
              console.log("3")
              if (vuelosmadrid[x].ciudades[y].ciudad === ciudaddestino) {
                console.log("4")
                for (z in vuelosmadrid[x].ciudades[y].fechas) {
                  console.log("5")
                  if (vuelosmadrid[x].ciudades[y].fechas[z].fecha === fechaorigen) {
                    console.log('hola');
                    constructor()
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
    };
```

The object JSON is this:

```
{"vuelosmadrid": [
                    {"Imagennaranja":"spain",
                    "Imagenverde":"spaingreen",
                    "Imagenamarilla":"spainyellow",
                    "Imagenrojo": "spainred",
                    "ciudades":
                        [
                            {"ciudad":"Barcelona",
                            "fechas":
                             [
                                {"fecha":"2014-11-05","precio": 50 },
                                {"fecha":"2014-11-06","precio": 40 }
                             ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    {"Imagennaranja":"francia",
                     "Imagenverde":"franciagreen",
                     "Imagenamarilla":"franciayellow",
                     "Imagenrojo": "franciared",
                     "ciudades":
                        [
                           {"ciudad":"Paris",
                            "fechas":
                                [
                                    {"fecha":"2014-11-05","precio": 190},
                                    {"fecha":"2014-11-06","precio": 225},
                                    {"fecha":"2014-11-06","precio": 225}
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    {"Imagennaranja":"portugal",
                     "Imagenverde":"portugalgreen",
                     "Imagenamarilla":"portugalyellow",
                     "Imagenrojo": "portugalred",
                     "ciudades":
                        [
                            {"ciudad":"Lisboa",
                             "fechas":
                                [
                                    {"fecha":"2014-11-05","precio": 45},
                                    {"fecha":"2014-11-06","precio": 75}
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }

            ]}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when the page loads the console says `Syntax error: Unexpected token }` in the line where I close the function `json`.

Comment: Your code has serious formating issues.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the spelling mistake... You haven't closed `$.getJSON` method with `)`

It should be:

```
function json(){ $.getJSON(
    "/JavaScript/dataBase2.json"
    function(data){ 
        $.window.vuelosmadrid = data; 
        //console.log(data.vuelosmadrid) check()
    }
    ); //added closing
}
```

Comment: Thank you¡¡ I have been stearing my code for a long time and I didn't realize. Really helpfull.

Comment: Formatting, like in my answer, helps a lot in spotting such errors.